# MySQL bulk parametrized inserts performance

Tags: mysql, bulkinsert, prepared-statement

I am looking for someone more knowledgable in terms of MySQL query optimizer / cache.

I have to perform bulk insert operation of dataset changing in size (so each time number of rows will change). I wanted to know if, assuming these queries are parametrized, thas bulk insert query will be cached / reused? So basically I'm wondering if MySQL is smart enough to see that these inserts are all the same and cache a single insert query (whether its insert-per-row or multiple rows on for one row)? Then reuse the optimized, cached query?

Just to give you more idea of data amount we talk about, it around 500-600 batches of bulk inserts and each bulk insert has unknown number of rows to be inserted (as in, it may be anything between 1 and 100000). They are executed one after another.

So will that bulk insert be cached and reused? If not, would splitting the bulk insert into small batches (like a single INSERT query with X rows) change it?

I'm not looking for another way of doing this as for now. Simply, because it is not possible given how the application is written, so I am only limited to parametrized vs non-parametrized query and one bulk insert vs multiple batches. This is then called X number of times for each "object" I have, which like I said already, may even be 500 or 600 times (but this I can't change for now).

## EDIT

I thought that this description may be vague, so here it is as a list:

1. Step into iteration of loop over objects
2. Identify data to be inserted for that object
3. Create a bulk insert query (non-parametrized currently, but I want to change that)
4. Execute bulk query
5. Go to another iteration

So what I really can change for now is points 3 and 4.

Comment: Is the data inside each batch related, or is there some sort of pattern?

Comment: I think you are talking about a Prepared, Parameterised query. You prepare A query once, then execute it MANY times replacing the parameters each time round the execute loop, These work using either `mysqli_` or `PDO`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen if you ask if there are relations between data in a bulk insert, then yes. It's a tree-like structure. But each object I loop over is unrelated in terms of data I insert to another object.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, prepared & parametrized queries. I can prepare the query, yes, but what if the number of rows I insert at each execution is different? This means these are different queries. That's why I'm asking if it would be better to split the bulk insert into equally "big" (in terms of rows) batches and reuse prepared query for that? Would that improve the performance? At the moment it takes up to 60 seconds to loop over objects and execute bulk inserts them. I can only optimize on single iteration though. P.S. I use C++ if that matters.

Comment: Not totally sure exectly whet you mean by bulk inserts. Can you add some example code to your quesiton

Comment: @RiggsFolly bulk as in 10000 rows inserted in a single query execution (single table). 10000 here is just an example. This number depends on the size of the tree structure I must save. So I can either have this X rows in one query, but I was thinking if using multiple executions of query (prepared) inserting Y rows instead would speed things up.